# Distribution parameterized by its median and value at risk (VaR)

Tags: quantiles, median, truncated-distributions

I am trying to find if there is an appropriate distribution whose parameterized by the median as a measure of center and VaR (Value at Risk) or CVaR (Conditional VaR, Tail VaR) as a dispersion. Is there such a distribution?

Comment: VaR and CVaR both require a parameter ($\alpha$) to be specified; they're both a collection of risk measures indexed by $\alpha$; Median is a specific quantile, so if you specify the distribution, you know the median, but with VaR and CVaR even if you completely specify the distribution you still don't know which one you might be talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any distribution with a nice quantile function can be paramterized by median and VaR. For example:

- A median of $m$ and a 95% VaR of $v$ can
  be realized with a uniform distribution over

$$[m-\frac{50}{45}(m-v), m+\frac{50}{45}(m-v)]$$

Almost any distribution whose quantile function has a nice integral can be paramterized by median and CVaR. For example:

- A median of $m$ and a 95% CVaR of $c$ can be realized with a uniform distribution over
  $$[m-\frac{50}{47.5}(m-c),m+\frac{50}{47.5}(m-c)]$$

Answer (score -1):

With VaR and CVaR, do you mean 'Value at Risk' and 'Conditional Value at Risk'? I don't know too much about finance, but from what I read about using the median instead mean as a central value, [Is it better to use mean or median](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_better_to_use_the_mean_or_median_in_describing_central_value_tendency_of_a_given_population_sample), it is not a good idea to use the median over mean if the distribution in question is continuous. This is because the median is the literal separator of the data from lower half to upper half where as the mean is a calculated central point. I did find something on risk encyclopedia, [How to calculate VaR](http://www.riskencyclopedia.com/articles/var_measure/), that goes through how to calculate VaR by finding a probability distribution of a portfolio's market value and it shows VaR as the dispersion from the middle(median) of the curve.

It looks like VaR and variance are one in the same. It just depends on the context of the situation, what you are analyzing.

Comment: Yes i mean "Value at Risk" and "Conditional Value at Risk". I want to compare the Median model with the Mean model and some other models. But i am confused about the "Probability Distributions" that i should use .In the case of mean and variance for example the Gaussian distribution is used , what about the Median? VaR? CVaR?

Comment: Couldn't you just replace the mean with the median in the pdf/cdf function and evaluate, since they are both measures of centrality.

Comment: even if i did so ..what about the VaR and CVaR?

Comment: Okay, I was told that you cannot simply replace the mean with median in a continuous distribution. The mean is regarded as the first moment of the curve(FYI: a moment is a quantitative measure of the shape of a curve - wikipedia), whereas the median is a literal divider of the distribution. So, it doesn't make sense to switch the mean for median. I don't think a distribution exists with the median as a parameter for this reason. As for VaR and CVaR, that is just the variance and conditional variance of the distribution. It all depends on what the distribution data is(portfolio value here).